# how can i get the scrollTop of "overflow: auto" on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html:

```
<div class="div1" id="div1">
  <section>
    <p>1</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {   height: 100;  overflow: auto; }
```

i try this jquery:

```
 $("#div1").scroll(function(){
            console.log($("#div1").scrollTop())});
```

how can i get scrollTop of div1 ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is this okay? :)

Comment: Your css should be .div1 {   height: 100px;  overflow: auto; }